# Free Heroku site can't provide a secure connection: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I just set up my first free Heroku site. It has a registration and log in system. I don't own a domain. When I go to visit the site when I'm not logged in to Heroku, chrome sends me the error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

I tried it in Safari, and I get a similar error:

Safari can't open the page "mypage.heroku.com" because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server "mypage.heroku.com"

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? Could someone please explain what is happening? I don't understand why it works while I'm logged into Heroku but won't let me access the page from any other device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app's domain will be `mypage.herokuapp.com`, not `.heroku.com`.
Going to that domain should give you no SSL error.